# How do I lazy-load styles for prod, where output-hashing (for cache busting) is enabled

Tags: hash, angular-cli, bundling-and-minification

In .angular-cli.json, you can specify styles as input,output, lazy. If lazy, it will not include it in index.html (it is up to you).  However, if --output-hashing is enabled (e.g. for production), it adds a hash value, so theme.scss becomes theme.6dc4d860143115033cae.bundle.css, not theme.bundle.css.

So, how do you know the actual filename?  The only thing I can think of right now is, after the build find all .*bundle.* files, and create a json file that provides a map of the unhashed file name to the hashed, place that in assets, and load it as part of a service.  But that seems a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry about this anymore.

**Output hashing was removed from lazy-loaded styles.**

Here is the PR: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/11491